# ¿Cómo hago para hacer un array multidimensional de 7x7 en JavaScript y cargarla con números Random?

Tags: javascript, array, random

Estoy tratando de crear una matriz de `7x7` con 2 bucle `for`, llenarla con números `random` y mostrarla, pero se me mezclo todo y me perdí.

```
var tamano =  7;
var matriz = new Array(tamano);
var mostrar = "";

for (i = 0; i < tamanio; i++){
matriz1[i]=new Array(tamanio);

var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
matriz[i][h] = num

for (i = 0;i < tamano; i ++) {
    for (h = 0; i <tamano; i++) {

    }
    matriz[i] = new Array(tamano);

}

document.write();
```

Comment: tiene que recorrer el segundo arreglo asi  for (h = 0; h <tamano-1; h++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo simple de como generar matrices, cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar.

```js
let generarMatriz = (size) => {
  let matriz = [];
  let random = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  for (let x = 0; x < size; x++){
    matriz[x] = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < size; y++){
      matriz[x][y] = random();
    }
  }
  return matriz;
};

console.log("Matriz",generarMatriz(7));
```